# xVal: Show Error Message for individual fields as well as the Summary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, xval

I'm using xVal in my MVC1.0 application and I'm trying to get client side validation to give a summary AND an individual error for each field. I can only get one or the other.

Only shows error message for each field:

```
Html.ClientSideValidation<StorefrontEditFormViewModel>("storefrontDetails")
```

Only shows summary:

```
Html.ClientSideValidation<StorefrontEditFormViewModel>   ("storefrontDetails").UseValidationSummary("validationSummary")
```

Does anyone know how I can get both to be displayed with xVal?